# d3.js append video from YT,Vimeo,

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, slideshow

i am using **d3.js** for creating dynamc slideshow. Texts and Images work correctly but on the other hand i dont know how could i **append video**. Any idea?

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
....
 canvas.append("image")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 125)
        .attr("height", "50px")
        .attr("width", "50px")
        .attr("xlink:href", "imageee.png")
        .call(ImageDrag);

 canvas.append("text")
        .text("hello")
        .attr("x", 145)
        .attr("y", 74)
        .style("fill", "yellow")
        .attr("font-size", 14)
        .call(TextDrag)
...
```

Comment: The typical method for adding videos into a webpage is by using an `iframe`. This is the code that YouTube provides when you go to Share > Embed.

Comment: thanks, but i tried this 

`function appendIframe() { 

canvas.append("iframe")
 .attr("x", 100)
 .attr("y", 50)
 .attr("height", "315px") 
 .attr("width", "560px")
 .attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9wdWiZ7D0l8")    .attr("frameborder","0");

 alert("nice"); 
} `

and alert me "nice" but i dont see it in the canvas